# How to implement scene changing in real-time?

Tags: animation

I want to implement real-time scene changing effects to make my game could changing from spring to summer, summer to fall, fall to winter. And Chaning effects like this game. [Giana Sisters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQcVgc4bmo4).

I think Giana Sisters use animation to transit from two scenes, but I dont know how to make these animations.

Is any other suggestions could make this effects?

Comment: From what I saw in that trailer, you can do that by crossfading the background and changing all the lights colors. Nothing fancy there. --now, making it look cool, that's a whole different story.

Comment: It's no simple fading, they're animating the change with models morphing etc.

Answer (score 1):

To do something like this you'll need an animation system being able to blend two different animations over each other (i.e. apply both at the same time).

Other than that, it's not that different from standard animations. The animation changing the appearance is just playing situational (i.e. during the "phase changes").

Something like this is trivial to do, if you're morphing different things (e.g. only switching colors).

The easiest way to do this would probably be some way to create some counter for the progress. For example - I'm using only two different states here - you could have summer and winter (ignore spring and fall for now).

Let's call this value `timeOfTheYear` with a valid range from `0` to `255` (i.e. a single byte).

To animate the time/change you just let the value alternate to/from the minimum and maximum values based on your game timing. E.g. the value starts at `0` (summer) and increases till it hits `255` (winter). It then goes back to `0`, back to `255`, etc. This change can happen with a specific velocity, e.g. `+-1` per millisecond.

You only do this change if you want to change time (e.g. when some special button is pushed).

Once this is implemented, you only have to animate the change as well.

As an example, you might be drawing leaves on trees. Set their transparency according to your `timeOfTheYear` value (e.g. 0 -> 100%, 32 -> 90%, 127 -> 80%, 192 -> 40%, etc.).

Instead of changing the opacity/transparency you could as well draw some animation frame based on this (which is what Giana Sisters is doing). For example, at 0 you draw the first frame, at 255 you draw the last frame - any other values in between draw steps between these.